# Google Chrome not loading correctly website with large minified css and scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I am developing my website and I recently minified with "minify" and joined all my css files into one. Also, instead of loading jQuery from my local file I am loading it from the jquery.com CDN. Since then, despite that it is loading correctly in Firefox and IE, it is not loading correctly
in Google Chrome. The css file is 81k large.

Comment: Clean the browser cache

Answer (score 0):

The browser might have cached things, try to clear the cache of the browser.

Your HTML might be incorrect. Make sure your structure is correct, analyze it with an html validator.

You might have an error, which might be displayed in chrome's console.